# Avoid using global scope in p5

Tags: javascript, webpack, scope, p5.js

I just started a new project in *p5*, I've already used it directly imported in the browser, but this time, since it's a more complex project, I'm going to use it in webpack.

I imported the library and bootstraped it in this way:

```
import * as p5 from 'p5';

function setup() {
  createCanvas(640, 480);
}

function draw() {
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    fill(0);
  } else {
    fill(255);
  }
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 80, 80);
}
```

But it doesn't work.

The reason is simple: webpack wraps the module in a local scope, and *p5* isn't aware of it.

For this reason, I assigned the functions to the global scope:

```
import * as p5 from 'p5';

window.setup = function () {
  createCanvas(640, 480);
}

window.draw = function () {
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    fill(0);
  } else {
    fill(255);
  }
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 80, 80);
}
```

And it works fine, but still looks wrong. I don't think that pollulating the global scope is the correct way of working with JS in 2019. Expecially if I'm using webpack and I'm about to implement TypeScript.

So, how can I tell *p5* to look for the functions in the module scope and not in the global one?

Comment: *"And it works fine, but still looks wrong."* Good instinct there. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd use [instance mode](http://staging.p5js.org/examples/instance-mode-instantiation.html), which doesn't rely on globals. Here's the example from that page:

```
var sketch = function( p ) {

  var x = 100; 
  var y = 100;

  p.setup = function() {
    p.createCanvas(700, 410);
  };

  p.draw = function() {
    p.background(0);
    p.fill(255);
    p.rect(x,y,50,50);
  };
};

var myp5 = new p5(sketch);
```

Live Example:

```js
var sketch = function( p ) {

  var x = 100; 
  var y = 100;

  p.setup = function() {
    p.createCanvas(700, 410);
  };

  p.draw = function() {
    p.background(0);
    p.fill(255);
    p.rect(x,y,50,50);
  };
};

var myp5 = new p5(sketch);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works, but it's like using a module inside another type of module. How can I use webpack modules? How can I use ES5 features like classes?

Comment: @CristianTraìna - As far as I can tell, this is how you do this with p5. Remember that p5 is targeted at designers and artists, not programmers, and intentionally makes technical choices with that in mind. Re using classes: You didn't ask that (which is good: you should ask *one* question per question). You asked how to avoid using globals. But I don't think you can readily use classes with p5. You could use an object initializer with methods and such on it, then copy those to the instance p5 gives your callback function, but...

Comment: For a more programmer-oriented experience, you might consider [d3.js](http://d3js.org), [processing.js](http://processingjs.org), [Raphaël](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/), or [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/).

Comment: "p5 is targeted at designers and artists, not programmers", couldn't disagree with this statement anymore if I tried. @T.J.Crowder  And recommending processing.js rather than p5.js for a more "programmer-oriented approach" makes no sense at all. All processing.js does is interprets Processing code into JavaScript.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you convinced me. Even if it's... weird. I mean, this solves the global scope issue, but what if I want two modules to interact? What if I want to avoid repeating `p.` at the beginning of every method or property, but still keeping a namespace? This is a critique to the library, not to your answer, I hope it's clear. But my question was about scopes, you are right

Comment: @LukeGarrigan - Quite right on processing.js, no idea how that slipped in that list. :-) Re the other, from the p5.js home page: *"p5.js is a JavaScript library that starst with the original goal of Processing, to make coding accessible for artists, designers, educators, and beginners, and reinterprets this for today's web."*

Comment: Yes, it makes it accessible for artists, designers, educators, and beginners does not in any way shape or form mean programmers shouldn't take advantage of its ease of use. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @LukeGarrigan - True. What makes it not programmer-oriented is its use of global variables, etc., leading to exactly questions like this. That makes it easier for everyone (artists, programmers) to use, but also makes it run contrary to fundamental programming principles. That's the kind of trade-off I mean. I'm not talking it down at all.

Comment: It's still powerful if you want to use your whole webpage as canvas. So I think I'm going to create an adapter and maybe publish it